# A Local version of Azure Table Storage

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-table-storage

Ok first of all I love Azure and table storage.

We're starting a new greenfield project which will be hosted as a SaaS model in the cloud. Azure Table storage is ideal for what we need but one thing stopping us from taking this route is the possibility of someone having to have the application deployed to their local web server rather than a cloud deployment.

This is something i'd rather avoid personally but unfortunately some people insist the their local setup is more secure than any data centre out there.

What i'd really like to know is if someone has created a local implementation of Azure Table Storage. I know microsoft have the emulator which in theory could be used (it stores the data in SQL which may be slow)

Anyone used the emulator for an internal deployment?
I'm happy to look at creating a wrapper for Azure Table Storage using their rest apis but didn't want to do something that's already been done.

Alternately can anyone recommend an alternate? I know there's RavenDB and MongoDB which also look good too but i've not had an exposure to how well they handle under load or  when to scale them out.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator is designed to simplify testing - it is definitely not intended to be used as part of a production deployment.

Is it possible to embrace both a cloud only (Azure Web role and Storage) and a hybrid design whereby your application can be hosted within your web server yet still use Azure Storage?

Jason

Comment: Thanks Jason but it's actually the data they want to keep locally. My personal recommendation would be to have their own private deployment in Azure whereby all data and application is isolated but some people insist the data being kept on site.